# Use sqldf inside a function with generic column references

Tags: r, function, sqldf

I'm trying to use the `sqldf` package inside a user-defined function in r with generic column names. I can only get it to work if the variable names match placeholder variable names (`x` and `y`) within the function. However, I want it to work regardless of the variable name fed into the function. Here is the example I've been playing with:

Here is the form that works:

```
df<-data.frame(X=as.factor(c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c")), Y=c(2.5,3,4,4,5.3,6,6.555,7,8))
df

Bar_Prep1<-function(data,x,y){
  library(sqldf)
  require(sqldf)
  dataframe<-sqldf("select a.[x] Grp, AVG(a.[y]) Mean, stdev(a.[y]) SD, Max(a.[y]) Max
                 from data a
                 group by a.[x]")
  dataframe$RD<-round(dataframe$Mean,digits=0)
  return(dataframe)
}

test<-Bar_Prep1(df,df$X,df$Y)
test
```

Which returns the following df:

```
  Grp     Mean        SD Max RD
1   a 3.166667 0.7637626   4  3
2   b 5.100000 1.0148892   6  5
3   c 7.185000 0.7400507   8  7
```

BUT, I want to be able to use the function on various column names, so I tried this:

```
df1<-data.frame(a=as.factor(c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c")), b=c(2.5,3,4,4,5.3,6,6.555,7,8))
df1
test1<-Bar_Prep1(df1,df1$a,df1$b)
test1
```

Returns the following errors: "Error: no such column: a.x"
"object 'test1' not found

So the question is, how do I need to modify my function code to accept variable names other than "x" and "y"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the names rather than the columns.  Change the `sqldf` call to `fn$sqldf` which will enable string interpolation using $.  Then in the `select` statement use `$x` and `$y`.

```
library(sqldf)

Bar_Prep1 <- function(data, x, y) {
  dataframe <- fn$sqldf("select 
      a.[$x] Grp, 
      AVG(a.[$y]) Mean, 
      stdev(a.[$y]) SD, 
      Max(a.[$y]) Max
    from data a
    group by a.[$x]")
  dataframe$RD <- round(dataframe$Mean, digits = 0)
  return(dataframe)
}

Bar_Prep1(df, "X", "Y")
##   Grp     Mean        SD Max RD
## 1   a 3.166667 0.7637626   4  3
## 2   b 5.100000 1.0148892   6  5
## 3   c 7.185000 0.7400507   8  7
```

Note that it would be possible to absorb the rounding into the SQL statement:

```
Bar_Prep1 <- function(data, x, y) {
  fn$sqldf("with tmp as (select 
      a.[$x] Grp, 
      AVG(a.[$y]) Mean, 
      stdev(a.[$y]) SD, 
      Max(a.[$y]) Max
    from data a
    group by a.[$x])
  select *, round(Mean) RD from tmp")
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much for the help. Really appreciate it. Cheers! P

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried both forms and neither worked. When I tried calling them via  Bar_Prep1(df1,df1$a, df1$b), they returned the following message: Error: no such column a.c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3).  When I tied calling them via Bar_Prep1(df1,a,b), the error message changed to : Error in eval(parse(text = paste(..., sep = "")), env) : 
  object 'a' not found. So not really sure what's going on here. I'm going to try restarting.

Comment: As the answer states and the example in the answer shows you have to pass the *names* as character strings.  If df1 has columns named a and b then use `Bar_Prep1(df1, "a", "b")` . You forgot the quotes.

Comment: Yeah I did, didn't I. Great. Cheers!